# c# getting the right form to show

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two forms a salaried employee and an hourly employee which has the employees details on it loading from a textfile. In my main form there is a listbox with the names of the employees, once one is clicked, i want to be able to press an edit employee details button on my main form and for the correct form to come up and I am struggling on how to do this. The code for my main form is here:

```
 public partial class MainForm : Form
 {
// The file used to store employee details
string employeesFile = "employees.txt";


// The collection used to hold the employee data
Employees employees;


public MainForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    employees = new Employees();
    if (!employees.Load(employeesFile))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Unable to load employees file");
    }
    else
    {
        PopulateListBox();
    }
}

private void PopulateListBox()
{
    listBoxEmployees.Items.Clear();
    foreach (Employee employee in employees)
    {
        listBoxEmployees.Items.Add(employee.LastName + "," + 
employee.FirstName);
    }
    listBoxEmployees.SelectedIndex = 0;
}

private void listBoxEmployees_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ }

private void buttonEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

my load method:

```
{
public bool Load(string employeesFile)
{
    bool status = false;
    StreamReader inputFile = null;
    string inputLine;

    if (!File.Exists(employeesFile))
    {
        return false;
    }
    try
    {
        inputFile = new StreamReader(employeesFile);
        if (inputFile != null)
        {
            inputLine = inputFile.ReadLine();
            while (inputLine != null)
            {
                Employee employeeEntry = 
EmployeeClass.NewEmployee(inputLine);
                if (employeeEntry != null)
                {
                    this.Add(employeeEntry);
                }
                inputLine = inputFile.ReadLine();
            }
            inputFile.Close();
        }
        status = true;
    }
    catch
    {
    }
    return status;
   }
 }
```

the employees class code from the load method:

```
 public class EmployeeClass
 {
 public static Employee NewEmployee(string employeeData)
 {
    if (employeeData.Length < 1)
    {
        return null;
    }
    switch (employeeData[0])
    {
        case 'S':
           return new SalariedEmployee(employeeData);

        case 'H':
            return new HourlyEmployee(employeeData);

        default:
            return null;
```

the hourly employee form:

```
public partial class Hourly_Employee : Form {

HourlyEmployee _employeeEntry;

public Hourly_Employee()
{
  InitializeComponent();
}


public HourlyEmployee employeeEntry
{
    get
    {
        return _employeeEntry;
    }
    set
    {
        _employeeEntry = value;
    }
}

private void Hourly_Employee_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBoxlastName.Text = _employeeEntry.LastName;
    textBoxfirstName.Text = _employeeEntry.FirstName;
    textBoxaddress.Text = _employeeEntry.Address;
    textBoxpostCode.Text = _employeeEntry.PostCode;
    textBoxphoneNumber.Text = _employeeEntry.PhoneNumber;
    dateTimePickerdateOfBirth.Text = 
_employeeEntry.DateOfBirth.ToString();
    textBoxhourlyPay.Text = _employeeEntry.HourlyPay.ToString();
    textBoxoverTimePay.Text = _employeeEntry.OvertimePay.ToString();
  }
 }
```

and lastly my salaried employee form:

```
public partial class Salary_Employee : Form
{
SalariedEmployee _employeeEntry;

public SalariedEmployee employeeEntry
{
    get
    {
        return _employeeEntry;
    }
    set
    {
        _employeeEntry = value;
    }
}

private void Salary_Employee_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBoxlastName.Text = _employeeEntry.LastName;
    textBoxfirstName.Text = _employeeEntry.FirstName;
    textBoxaddress.Text = _employeeEntry.Address;
    textBoxpostCode.Text = _employeeEntry.PostCode;
    textBoxphoneNumber.Text = _employeeEntry.PhoneNumber;
    dateTimePickerdateOfBirth.Text = 
 _employeeEntry.DateOfBirth.ToString();
    textBoxSalary.Text = _employeeEntry.Salary.ToString();
 }
```

any help with this issue would be great!!

Comment: What is the problem exactly?

Comment: a duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44345739/c-sharp-showing-the-right-form (now deleted by author) from another user. collective homework?

Comment: @Sty id like to be able to click the edit button while a name is selected in the listbox and the right form show with the employyes info in

Comment: You have shared alot of code, including an empty `buttonEdit_Click()` method. If you wrote the other code, surely you can make an attempt to handle the button click event? If you try to solve the issue and run into more specific issues, we're here to help.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis I have tried a few different ways but couldnt get it to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to add the employee objects to the listbox instead of only strings containing the employee names. This allows you to retrieve the selected employee directly from the listbox. Otherwise you would need a way to find the employee object belonging to a name.

Use the type of the selected item to determine the employee type and the employee form.

```
private void buttonEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Get the selected employee from the listBox.
    object employee = listBoxEmployees.SelectedItem;

    if (employee != null) { // An employee has been selected.
         // Use the new C# 7.0 switch syntax in order to switch by employee type.
        switch (employee) {
            case SalariedEmployee sEmployee:
                var sfrm = new Salary_Employee(); // Open the salaried employee form..
                sfrm.employeeEntry = sEmployee;
                sfrm.Show();
                break;
            case HourlyEmployee hEmployee:
                var hfrm = new Hourly_Employee(); // Open the hourly employee form.
                hfrm.employeeEntry = hEmployee;
                hfrm.Show();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

In case you are using an older C# version you can test a type with

```
if (employee is SalariedEmployee) {
    var frm = new Salary_Employee();;
    frm.employeeEntry = (SalariedEmployee)employee;
    frm.Show();
} else if (employee is HourlyEmployee) {
    var frm = new Hourly_Employee();
    frm.employeeEntry = (HourlyEmployee)employee;
    frm.Show();
}
```

---

By default, an object's `ToString` method returns the name of the object's type. Enable the listbox to display the employees correctly by overriding the `ToString` method inherited from `object` in the common base class `Employee`.

```
public class Employee
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return LastName + ", " + FirstName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for you reply. I have tried this but I am geting the errors on HourlyEmployee and SalariedEmployee of "an expression of type employeeclass can not be handled by a pattern of type SalariedEmployee/HourlyEmployee. By the common base class did you mean the employee class which holds the first name last name address etc etc?

Comment: Probably your `SalariedEmployee` and `HourlyEmployee` classes do not derive from `EmployeeClass` as I expected. Therefore just type the selected employee as `object` (no casting is required in this case).

Comment: I changed the employee class to Employee. But have the errors from these two lines     var frm = new Hourly_Employee(); 
                        frm.employeeEntry = hEmployee;      firstly "frm" A local variable or function named frm is already defined in this scope. Then on the second line the "frm" has the error "use of unassigned local variable. With the last error been on hEmployee "Cannot implicitly convert type HRApplication.HourlyEmployee to HRApplication.SalariedEmployee

Comment: I cannot help you with errors, if you don't explain them. Visual Studio usually gives very accurate error messages. Read them carefully. They might point you in the right direction.

Comment: I renamed `frm` to `sfrm and `hfrm` respectively.

Comment: Thank you, Ive sorted the error codes out now. But when I run the application and click the edit button nothing happens! If you have an idea why?

Comment: Because you added strings to the listbox instead of employees. Do `listBoxEmployees.Items.Add(employee);` instead. Override the `ToString` method of the employee class and let it return `employee.LastName + "," + 
employee.FirstName`. This enables the listbox to correctly display employee objects.

Comment: I have managed to get the first part to work, I can now get the forms to open with the information on the form just dont know how or where to put the code for the lastname and first name for the listbox

Comment: override `ToString()` in the common base class `Employee` which hold the names.